# Row Offset in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT name FROM employee
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

I write this query but getting error msg. plz help me

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>   Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: This is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - you cannot use this in 2005 ....

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sub query like:

```
select top 5 name
from (
      select top 10 id, name
      from employee
      order by id) as x
order by id desc
```

This will return rows 6 through 10.